# Как удалить WebStorm в Ununtu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix

Как удалить WebStorm в Ununtu? Или как узнавать название подобных программ для удаления.
Пробовал командой

```
sudo apt-get remove webstorm (и web-storm тоже)
```

но так не удаляет, пишет что-то вроде:

> Не удалось найти пакет webstorm

Comment: вебшторм не ставится через пакетный менеджер, вы можете только руками удалить файлы, или, если ставили через toolbox, удалить там

Answer (score 2):

```
rm -rf ~/WebStorm-145.1616.9/

rm -rf ~/.Webstorm2016.1/

rm -rf ~/.gnome/apps/jetbrains-webstorm.desktop

rm -rf ~/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-webstorm.desktop
```

Примерно так.